# Fade out UIButton slowly

Tags: uibutton, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to add an animation to fade out a button when it is tapped. The code I am using at the moment just waits a few seconds and then fades out the button almost instantly. I was wondering how I can start to fade out the button as soon as it is tapped and make the fade last for around a second?

This is the code that I am using at the moment:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, 
    delay: 0, 
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, 
    animations: {
        self.valueEnter.alpha = 0
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This should work. The most likely reason the animation would be choppy is if you’re doing some heavy work on the main thread while it’s supposed to be running. What else is in the method where you’re performing this animation?

Comment: There isn't really anything else is within this method. The only purpose of it is to dismiss the keyboard. It doesn't seem choppy, it just seems like it is delayed for a second or two and then it performs the animation.

Comment: Which thread are you running this code on? Your symptoms may well occur if you don't run it on the UI thread. Can we get more context, please? Is this code running as part of a completion handler, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that for fading the button out, rather than using

```
    self.valueEnter.alpha = 100
```

I should have been using

```
    self.valueEnter.alpha = 1
```

I didn't realise that the range was between 0 and 1 rather than 0 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select button in the storyboard/nib
2. Open **Connections Inspector**
3. Connect button **Touch Down** and **Touch Up Inside** events:

[image]

... to the following methods:

```
@IBAction func fadeButtonTouchDown(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.highlighted = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5,
        delay: 0,
        options: .CurveLinear & .AllowUserInteraction & .BeginFromCurrentState,
        animations: {
            sender.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func fadeButtonTouchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.highlighted = false
}
```

**Remarks:** methods should be added to your view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this seems to do the same thing. Nothing happens for about a second and then the button fades out quickly.

Comment: I've checked the code again and it works just fine. Tested in emulator and iPhone4. Please double check that button events are connected properly and animation options are set exactly as in the code example. You can visually verify that animation starts immediately by setting animation duration to 0.1 and toggling slow animations in emulator; easy no notice that animation start just after user tap the button.